# How can I generate prediction intervals for Azure AutoML timeseries forecasts?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

Is it possible to generate prediction intervals for time series forecasts when using a Azure AutoML trained models? Could we get the training errors out of the process and use them for bootstrapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate forecast quantiles. See the following notebook for more details: https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/automated-machine-learning/forecasting-forecast-function/auto-ml-forecasting-function.ipynb

Comment: I don't suppose there is any way to get the many models accelerator to call forecast_quantiles() is there?

Comment: feature request for many models accelerator: https://github.com/microsoft/solution-accelerator-many-models/issues/125

Comment: No worries- this is on our backlog for Many Models as a few customers have requested it recently. Hopefully we can prioritize it soon. Thanks for logging it on GitHub!

Comment: I'll try to get some code added to that ticket as soon as I have something working locally...